# How can I assign a JavaScript variable by parsing a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a database server that will be running a script to generate this given file daily:

```
{"data": [
{"variable":"var1","value": "123"},
{"variable":"var2","value": "456"},
{"variable":"var3","value": "789"}]}
```

I am trying to parse this file to set three javascript variables for a HTML canvas element.

So far, I'm thinking I'll parse the JSON file

```
var JSONfile = './file.json';
var getData = JSON.parse(JSONfile);
```

Then a `for` loop to assign the variables

```
for (i = 0; i < getData.length; i++) {
    var getData.variable=getData.Value;
}
```

And I'm hoping to get results of:

```
var var1 = 123;
var var2 = 456;
var var3 = 789;
```

But `var getData.variable=getData.Value;` breaks. What am I missing?

Comment: The `JSON.parse()` API expects a string containing JSON syntax, not the name of a file.

Comment: @Pointy is correct ... you need to do an AJAX call to get the JSON contents, then parse the contents returned from that call.

Comment: try using $.getJSON({'url',parameter,callback}); [http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/]

Comment: `$.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data.JSONdata, function(i, f) {
        var f.number = f.value;
    });
});`

It still breaks on var f.number... unexpected token .

How can I set a variable name to a value from the object?

Answer (score 1):

JSON.parse() expects a JSON string, when you are passing it a file.

The first thing you need to do is use AJAX to get the contents of the file into a variable.  Either use a library like jQuery (see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) or from scratch in JavaScript.  But don't waste your time on the "from scratch" version unless you have to.

Use jQuery to get the contents of the file into an object, and pass the inner data (an array) to a function called doSomething():

```
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON("./file.json", function (data) {
        }).success(function (data) {
            myArr = data.data;
            doSomething(data.data);
        });
    });
```

Here, you iterate through the passed array, which contains elements that have a .variable and a .value property.  This writes both properties of each element to the console, for your viewing pleasure:

```
    function doSomething(arr) {
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            console.log(arr[i].variable + ': ' + arr[i].value);
        }
    }
```

You can also access the properties directly by the index as follows:

```
alert(jsonFromFile.data[2].variable);  // Will alert "var3"
alert(jsonFromFile.data[2].value);     // Will alert "789"
```

Comment: Got most of that working. Is there a way to assign both the variable name and value from the JSON?

`var jsonFromFile.data[i].variable = jsonFromFile.data[i].value`

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the ajax call and accessing both .variable and .value properties of each array element.

Comment: I continue to get an `Unknown Token .` error when trying to name a variable with the properties.

`var jsonFromFile.data[i].variable = jsonFromFile.data[i].value` is what gives the error.

Comment: var jsonFromFile.data[i].variable = jsonFromFile.data[i].value attempts to overwrite the .variable with the .value.  Is that what you want to do? I would think your goal would be to extract the contents out of jsonFromFile into something more useful that you use to do the rest of your work with.
Perhaps if I knew what you do with the values after retrieving them, I could suggest how to go about it.

Comment: as opposed to setting

`var1 = 123
var2 = 456
var3 = 789` manually

I want to set those three variable names and values from the JSON file.

Comment: Do you always know how many values will be in the JSON file, and do you always know what the .variable will be (e.g. "var1", etc.)?

Comment: Since it will be updated by a server script I don't have control over, I'd rather do it programmtically

Comment: Are you talking about the process of reading the JSON or creating it?  If reading, then think array form would be the best solution - you can always find out how many elements there are and reference them programmatically by index, and each element's properties can also be referenced by index.  As soon as you start creating individual named variables, you lose options.

Comment: I'm trying some array based solutions now.